# Python | librosa: how to stretch signal in time by adding more points

Tags: python-3.x, time, signal-processing, wav, librosa

I need help figuring out how to stretch a sample of, say, from 0.25 to 1 second using [librosa package](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.effects.time_stretch.html). I suppose `librosa.effects.time`_stretch is a function to do so, but instead of stretching a signal, it does something else. What is the correct way of applying it or some other `librosa` or `numpy` function (or `pydub`)?

Here is my attempt using 16 KHz sampling rate, i.e. 4K samples is given over 0.25 second time period. As the output, I need 16K samples for the full 1 second duration, keeping the sampling rate constant.

```
import numpy as np, librosa
x = np.sin(np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 4000))  # wav sample
y = librosa.effects.time_stretch(x, rate=4000/16000)
plt.plot(x)  # plotted in blue
plt.plot(y)  # plotted in orange
```

that yields the following plot:

[image]

Notably, the sine signal was not stretched. I'm using sin() as an example. The intent is to stretch voice audio wav files, where the analytical function is unknown.

Answer (score 3):

I think that time_stretch applies some processing to try to preserve the pitch of the audio. What you want is probably

```
y = librosa.core.resample(x, 4000, 16000)
```

which gives this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. I thought the pitch would be lower, if I am stretching. Your plot seems to show what I need, hopefully, with a new sample size of 16K points.